Are there any reasons for not using ReadOnlyMemory<T> instead of IReadOnlyList<T> to make sure an array is not modified?
I often use IReadOnlyList<double> for arrays of doubles (or other value types) to indicate that sure data is not to be modified:
class X {
public void ProcessSomePreviouslyCalculatedResults(IReadOnlyList<double> data) {
 // do something with data
}

I know that there is ImmutableArray<T>, which guarantees that the content cannot be modified (unlike IReadOnlyList<double> which could be casted to double[]) but introduces another level of indirection. I wonder if ReadOnlyMemory<T> would be a better choice. In the documentation and the guidelines the motivation for using (ReadOnly)Memory<T> is always the replacement for (ReadOnly)Span<T> at places where the latter cannot be used.
Are there any drawbacks for using ReadOnlyMemory<T> at places where I want to pass a readonly array around?
One thing I notice is that one has to use
 MemoryMarshal.ToEnumerable(readOnlyMemoryInstance).Select(...)

instead of
 ireadOnlyListInstance.Select(...)

Are there any more drawbacks?

This question is similar to: C# IReadOnlyList protection instantlly subverted by downcast, or am I missing something?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

The other question does not even mention ReadOnlyMemory, I don't see how it could be similar.

Using ReadOnlyMemory<T> in an attempt to ensure that the contents cannot be modified won't work due to the existence of MemoryMarshal.TryGetArray(). As such, unless you intend to represent array slices, I'd think that using IReadOnlyList<T>  would be the best approach.

@MatthewWatson I just want to indicate that the data should be not modified. As I stated in the question the only type which really guarantees immutability is ImmutableArray<T>. IReadOnlyList<T> can be casted to the underlying array as well.

Even ImmutableArray<T> doesn't guarantee that you can't modify the array because you can use ImmutableArray.AsMemory() to get a ReadOnlyMemory that you can pass to MemoryMarshal.TryGetArray() to get a writable array. Given that you only want to indicate that the data should not be modified, then IReadOnlyList<T> will do that, so I can see no reason to complicate things by using ReadOnlyMemory.

In other words, you can protect against accident but not against fraud - so pick the obvious solution: IReadOnlyList<T>.

I see. So why do you think ReadOnlyMemory<T> is more complex than IReadOnlyList<T>?

"Complex" is your personal wording no one used that.  The more concrete in used classes used you get the less usable code that uses it tend to be. Why enforcing a user of class x to convert from an already IReadOnlyList class derivate he might have to a ReadOnlyMemory he doesn't have?  If you want to indicate the list won't get changed by ProcessSomePreviouslyCalculatedResults then IReadOnlyList does that and keeps it more usable then a version for a more specific class.

@MarkusParker Well for starters you can't use foreach directly with ReadOnlyMemory<T>.  You also can't index into it. Both of those things you can do with IReadOnlyList<T>.

@MatthewWatson You are right. I did not notice, since the documentation indicated that ReadOnlyMemory<T> is similar to ReadOnlySpan<T>.  But while the later has an enumerator and indexer access, the former has not. So, your last comment would be a reasonable answer to the question if it had not been closed.
